# how to push map to a new array using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following code which is inside for each loop

```
    let array:[];

    result =  campaignsPerAffiliate.map(campaign => campaign.id)// returns 0001,00ec6,0caa4
```

now I want to push all these to an array one after another and because we are inside for each there will be more numbers so I will end up with [0001,00ec6,0caa4,000,1111]

```
  result.forEach(element => {
  array=array.push(element)
});
```

this doesnt seem to work

Comment: Remove `array=`. It's setting the whole array to the result of `array.push`, which will only be one value. Consider creating a copy instead? `array = result.slice()`

Comment: Is array defined variable? Share all of the foreach loop which you are talking about.

Comment: I know you didn‘t ask but array=array.concat(result) would also work.

Answer (score 1):

[`Array.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) returns the new length of the array, not the array. Thus, if you want to do it your way, you need to remove `array=`.

However, combining arrays can be done much easier with [`Array.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat).

See an example of both working properly here:

```js
let array = [];
let result = ["001", "002", "003"];
console.log("With concat: ", array.concat(result));
result.forEach(val=>{
  array.push(val);
});
console.log("With forach: ", array);
```